# I need to minimize the number of glDraw* calls

Tags: performance, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I'm working on a little 2D graphics/game library for personal use and currently I'm trying to think of a way to improve performance when drawing tiled maps. Currently I am creating a static GL_QUADS VBO for each tile in the map and then drawing it to the screen. Each VBO is referencing a texture loaded into memory which is sub-imaged and mapped to the VBO.

Currently, I have a 20 x 20 tile map that I am testing with. With my current implementation, since I have to draw each individual tile, that is 400 glDraw* calls every frame.

Is there any way to, for example, make each row of the tile map ONE VBO? This would reduce the glDraw* calls to 20, for this example. How would I map the sub-images? Individual tiles can be rotated.

I have seen some references to using a Texture Atlas. Would that be a good alternative? Any useful links on how to implement this in opengl?

CODE:

Current render method:

```
public void render() {
    texture.bind();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    for (SpriteSheet spriteSheet : spriteSheets) {
        VBO vbo = spriteSheet.getVBO();
        float angle = spriteSheet.getAngle();

        vbo.bind();
        if (angle != 0) {
            glPushMatrix();

            Vector2f position = spriteSheet.getPosition();

            glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, 0);
            glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
            glTranslatef(-position.x, -position.y, 0);

            glVertexPointer(Vertex.positionElementCount, GL_FLOAT, Vertex.stride, Vertex.positionByteOffset);
            glColorPointer(Vertex.colorElementCount, GL_FLOAT, Vertex.stride, Vertex.colorByteOffset);
            glTexCoordPointer(Vertex.textureElementCount, GL_FLOAT, Vertex.stride, Vertex.textureByteOffset);

            glDrawArrays(vbo.getMode(), 0, Vertex.elementCount);

            glPopMatrix();
        }
        else {
            glVertexPointer(Vertex.positionElementCount, GL_FLOAT, Vertex.stride, Vertex.positionByteOffset);
            glColorPointer(Vertex.colorElementCount, GL_FLOAT, Vertex.stride, Vertex.colorByteOffset);
            glTexCoordPointer(Vertex.textureElementCount, GL_FLOAT, Vertex.stride, Vertex.textureByteOffset);

            glDrawArrays(vbo.getMode(), 0, Vertex.elementCount);
        }
        vbo.unbind();
    }

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    texture.unbind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

A texture atlas one option, but you could use a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` as well, using the 3rd texture coordinate to select which layer to use.

The next thing to think about is *instancing*: Have a single quad in the buffer and make OpenGL draw it several times, using an additional buffer to select texture layer and rotation based on the drawn instance.

Comment: Which of those 3 options would be the easiest to implement? I am not familiar with these because I'm just started OpenGL not too long ago.

Comment: @cstuts: GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY is the most accessible. Using that will give you a huge performance boost, because you're getting rid of three bottlenecks at once: Large number of glDrawCalls, small batch size and texture switches. Each of those are detrimental for rendering performance, so getting those out of the way will help you big time.

Comment: Texture arrays is definitely the way to go.